# Using socket.io connection as a module

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I created a queue system via Rabbitmq and send notifications to users via socket. There are 3 files basically.

```
-index.js            //some functions to save data and send to Rabbitmq 
-socket.js           //socket io modules 
-consumer.js         //some functions to consume data from Rabbitmq
```

When npm run index.js and consumer.js are started.

**index.js**

```
const Express = require('express');
const app = Express();

//init server 
server = app.listen(3000);
//init socket io
require('./socket').initialize(server);
```

**socket.js**

```
const sio = require('socket.io');

let io;
module.exports = {
    //Initialize the socket server
    initialize: (server) => {
        io = sio(server, {
            cors: {
                origin: '*',
            }
        });
        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('New client connected with id = ', socket.id);
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                console.log("User disconnected");
            });
        });
    },
    //return the io instance
    getInstance: () => {
        return io;
    }
}
```

**consumer.js**

```
const socket = require('./socket');
const io = socket.getInstance();
console.log("io", io);
//io is undefined
```

Io returns undefined in consumer.js. Where is mistake?

Comment: How is **consumer.js** used/loaded? If **index.js** is loaded first (before **consumer.js**) in the same node process, `io` should get initialized, otherwise it will remain `undefined`.

Comment: "start": "concurrently \"node index.js\" \"node consumer.js\"" I used concurrently for to keep alive consumer.js what is the best method?

Comment: You can't call `socket.getInstance()` until someone has called `socket.initialize()` first.  You don't show where `consumer.js` is loaded so we can't follow the full sequence of module loading, but it appears that `consumer.js` is getting loaded before you initialize socket..

Comment: I modified my codes and removed concurrently and used consumer.js as a module and started with a initialize function. After I got io thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `socket.getInstance()` until someone has called `socket.initialize()` first.

You don't show where `consumer.js` is loaded so we can't follow the full sequence of module loading, but it appears that `consumer.js` is getting loaded before you initialize socket and thus it is trying to call `socket.getInstance()` before there's a socket instance to get.

When using methods that return state that built from previous methods, it is obviously important that things are called in the right order.